# Creating sets with elements from different types

Tags: java, algorithm, set

Recently, I came across a requirement in one of my project groups where in I need to create sets from different types of variables. Here is an example:
I have a list of (lets say) string where every string is associated with a type. So a list has: [var11: Type1, var12: Type1, var21: Type2, var31: Type3, var32: Type3, var33: Type3].

Now, I want to create a function:

```
    public List<String> getSetsWithTypes(String[] types) {
      // Iterate through types and create sets
    }
```

So, if I call the function with:
1. types = {"Type1", "Type2"}, it must return:

```
    ["var11:var21", "var12:var21"]
```

2. types = {"Type1", "Type3"}, it must return:

```
    ["var11:var31", "var11:var32", "var11:var33", "var12:var31", "var12:var32", "var12:var33"]
```

3. types = {"Type1", "Type2", "Type3"}, it must return:

```
    ["var11:var21:var31", "var11:var21:var32", "var11:var21:var33", "var12:var21:var31"...and so on]
```

The types are dynamic in nature and also the number of variables.
Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem? Can you add it as part of the question? This question looks like it is asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: Well, right now I am trying to think of some way to solve this. As soon as I get some concrete way, I shall post it. The reason for posting this question was to get some idea, if anyone came across similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a way to resolve this. Here is the explanation:
For example, we have:

```
    Types          : Type1 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type 4 |
    Number of vars :   2   |   3    |    1   |    2   |
    Toggle rate    :   6   |   2    |    2   |    1   |
```

Toggle rate T(i) = N(i+1) * N(i+2) * ... * N(n), in our case n = 4 and N(i) = number of vars of Type i.

```
    /* Assumptions: Each type has it's own column, so variable index
                    at column 4 will always be for Type 4.
    */
    int currentColumn = numberOfTypes.length;
    while (--currentColumn > -1) {
        // For each currentCol calculate combination
        // numberOfVariablesAtCurrentCol = typeSize[colPointer]
        // if there are more than 1 variables of certain type
        if (typeSize[currentColumn] > 1) {
            // Toggle rate is the integer value after which the var index would change for any column
            final int toggleRate = findToggleRate(params, currentColumn);
            int currentTogglePos = 1, varIndex = 0;
            for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < rows; currentRow++) {
                variableCombination[currentRow][currentColumn] = varIndex;
                // Reset currentTogglePos, if needed
                if (++currentTogglePos > toggleRate) {
                    currentTogglePos = 1;
                    // Reset varIndex, if required, only at toggle boundary
                    if (++varIndex >= typeSize[currentColumn])
                        varIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, what I finally get is:

```
    Types          : Type1 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type 4 |
    Number of vars :   2   |   3    |    1   |    2   |
    Toggle rate    :   6   |   2    |    2   |    1   |
    ---------------------------------------------------
    VariableIndex  :   0       0         0        0
    Every col gives:   0       0         0        1
      it's type    :   0       1         0        0
                       0       1         0        1
                       0       2         0        0
                       0       2         0        1
                       1       0         0        0
                       1       0         0        1
                       1       1         0        0
                       1       1         0        1
                       1       2         0        0
                       1       2         0        1
```

Well, this is the only way I could think of. Please suggest, if there exists some more efficient way.